# Match a pattern and insert text after it selectively in a large file

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I'm working with a very large size of code and need to rename a lot of APIs. This includes prefixes for all the API. My API names looks something like :

```
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighterDoMeAFavor(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, void *Favor)
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighterGetInLine(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, void *Line)
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighterSetATicketForMe(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, void *Ticket)
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighterHelpMeNowInterrupt(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, void *FighterReference)
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighterAreYouOk(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, unsigned int HowAreYou)
```

I want to change all these names by adding an underscore to the API names.
I would like the result to be something as below,

```
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter_DoMeAFavor(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, void *Favor)
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter_GetInLine(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, void *Line)
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter_SetATicketForMe(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, void *Ticket)
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter_HelpMeNowInterrupt(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, void *FighterReference)
MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter_AreYouOk(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *FighterInstance, unsigned int HowAreYou)
```

However, I want to replace the text only in the API names and not in other places in the code. I could use `s/FooFighter/FooFighter_/g`, but that will also make changes that I don't want.

I could do this is many ways by using a script and doing grep and replacing.
However, there must be a faster and smarter way to do this using a single command (hopefully with sed). Can someone enlighten me how to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the following `sed` expression (using [Basic Regular Expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax) syntax):

```
s/\(\bMyfoobarFilename_FooFighter\)\([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\b\)/\1_\2/g
```

where

- `\b` escape sequence stands for a "word boundary" (GNU extension);
- `\( ... \)` creates a group that can be referenced in the "replacement" part of the `s/regexp/replacement/` command;
- `\1` and `\2` are references to the first and the second groups;
- `g` instructs *sed* to apply the replacement to all matches to the "regexp", not just the first;
- `\+` matches one or more (GNU extension).

#### Perl as an alternative to GNU sed

As @Wiktor Stribiżew and @Ed Morton remarked, `\+` and `\b` are GNU extensions. You can replace `\+` with `\{1,\}`. But I couldn't find the appropriate POSIX-compliant replacement for `\b`. In the case if GNU sed is not available, you can use Perl as follows:

```
perl -i -npe \
's/(\bMyfoobarFilename_FooFighter)(\p{L}+\b)/\1_\2/g' file
```

where `\p{L}` is a [Unicode character property](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5Cp%7B%7D-and-%5CP%7B%7D) standing for a letter. The rest is similar to the sed expression above.

---

Your snippets look like C/C++ function prototypes, so you, probably, would like to modify the function calls and function pointers as well, e.g.:

```
while (MyfoobarFilename_FooFighterHelpMeNowInterrupt ()
  && MyfoobarFilename_FooFighterSetATicketForMe())
  {
    /* ... */
  }

void (*fptr)(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter *, void *) =
  &MyfoobarFilename_FooFighterGetInLine;
```

Comment: Just note that `\+` is a GNU sed extension, but OP has not specified the sed version in the question, so it is appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sed "s/\(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter\)\(\S*(\)/\1_\2/g" file.txt
```

explanation:

```
s/                                  # substitute
\(MyfoobarFilename_FooFighter\)     # searchstring in \1
\(\S*(\)                            # the rest to the bracket in \2
/\1_\2                              # insert '_' between \1 and \2
/g                                  # global
```